# Resizing the whole figure

Tags: floats, input

Each of my article figures is in a separate `.tex` file (in a figure environment and has `\includegraphics`) and I use `\input` to include each in my article. The `.tex` files were generated automatically using the MATLAB programs I wrote.

I want to use the same `.tex` figures within my `beamer` presentation but they do not fit.  How can I resize them?  I tried:

> \scalebox{.5}{\input{myfig.tex}}

without success.

---

This is an example `myfig.tex`

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{myfig.eps}\\
Some text
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: You can use the option scale for `\incudegraphics`

Comment: Please provide an MWE. the `scalebox` approach may be failing because of how you structured `myfig.tex`, we need to see a bit more of your approach to help you (but not too much otherwise it's difficult to cut through the noise)

Comment: It's probably best to generate a pdf file for each figure (using the `standalone` document class) and then you can use `\includegraphics` with specified width to scale them to your liking.

Comment: Well, you can't `\scalebox` a `figure` environment. But we still need some more info I think. Do you set the `width` key for `\includegraphics` explicitly in your `.tex` files?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No width key.  I included an example in my updated question.

Comment: @Bordaigorl I added an example in the question.

Comment: Now we can see the problem. `figure` is a floating environment, you cannot scale that. You want to scale what's inside it or use the `scale` option of `\includegraphics` directly. This means that you either have to restructure what you put in myfig.tex for reusability (i.e. put the figure env outside the `\input{myfig}`) or create a macro that does the appropriate wrapping with some scaling argument or do some hacking to inject the scaling inside the figure as Werner does

Comment: An alternative is making the width of the figure relative to the line width as in `\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{myfig.eps}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this version of `\scalefiginput[<scale>]{<file>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myfig.tex}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image} \\
    Some text
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{filecontents*}

\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\newcommand{\scalefiginput}[2][1]{%
  % Update \includegraphics to scale its argument
  \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\scalebox{#1}{\oldincludegraphics[##1]{##2}}}%
  \input{#2}% Input figure
  % Restore \includegraphics
  \let\includegraphics\oldincludegraphics
}
\begin{document}

\input{myfig.tex}

\scalefiginput{myfig.tex}

\scalefiginput[.5]{myfig.tex}

\end{document}
```

The macro updates the way `\includegraphics` functions, changing it into a `\scalebox{<scale>}{\includegraphics[..]{...}}` version just for the inclusion of the `<file>`.

The `<scale>` is optional (defaulting to `1`). You can also make it mandatory, if needed.

---

If you wish to scale everything (image *and* text), the following should do the trick:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,environ}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myfig.tex}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{example-image} \\
    Some text
  \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{filecontents*}

\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\newcommand{\scalefiginput}[2][1]{{%
  \RenewEnviron{tabular}[1]{%
    \scalebox{#1}{\begin{oldtabular}{##1}
      \BODY
    \end{oldtabular}}}%
  \input{#2}%
}}

\begin{document}

\input{myfig.tex}

\scalefiginput{myfig.tex}

\scalefiginput[.5]{myfig.tex}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to redefine the `tabular` environment so you can capture its entire contents and scale it to your liking.

Comment: Thank you.  I can use your solution to some extent.  Your solution does not rescale the text underneath though. Any ideas?

Comment: @Seeda: That's a bizarre request. However, see the updated answer.

Comment: I defined a scalefiginput and a scaletabinput.  Can they both used together since includegraphics is within the tabular environment?  Mine fails.